# Best practices that programmers should follow when developing in a Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment Environment

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Hey guys I work with a team of four people and only two of us really push changes to the Master Branch. As a result we communicate regularly to ensure we are not working on the same file of the solution to avoid merge conflicts. Definitely not the best practices.

However, we will be bringing in more people to work with us and it was proposed to switch to a Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment environment. I understand the concept of a CICD environment, but creating such environment will be the responsibility of another team.

My task however is coming up with a document for developers on how we should program going forward. Every time I Google something like "CICD Best Practices" I get results for building the CICD environment, however I am interested on best practices developers must follow when programming in a CICD environment as opposed to building a CICD environment.

I am aware of the obvious "Commit your changes often, document your code, use good names". **So I am trying to track down any publication or sources (from Microsoft, Amazon, etc) that might mention best practices that are not so obvious. Could anyone point me in the right direction?**

Please and thanks!

Comment: See my article for some of the points, hope it helps - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/06/04/7-best-practices-modern-cicd/

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best workflow is to restrict access to the master branch, no one should be allowed to push to it.

All changes should be made through PRs and pass all the tests defined in your cl pipeline.

In that way you can keep your master branch always with working code and deploy it directly to a staging environment. Once you have acceptable code on master you can make a release and have your CD deploy it to production.

Comment: Thanks for the response.